# MSDeploy is not deploying all the views on IIS

Tags: c#, iis, msbuild, cmd, msdeploy

I am  deploying an MVC application on IIS using the below commands

> **C:..\MSBuild.exe X:\WebApp.csproj /t:Package   /p:Configuration=Release /p:PackageLocation=x:\WepApp\WebApp.zip**
>
> **C:..\webapp.deploy.cmd /Y /M:192.168.1.12 /U:milton /P:xx**

The application is getting deployed on IIS successfully but All the Views content is not coming under the deployed folder.

I am unable to browse particular cshtml page except home page

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the missing views "Included" in the project file *and* marked with a "Build Action" of "Content"? If not, they won't be included in the package and thus won't be deployed.